# How to include DatePipe in HTML to print lastModifiedDate

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload, pipe, angular2-forms

I have file-upload.component.ts where I import DatePipe

`import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';`

then I

`export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  datePipe = new DatePipe();
}`

and in file-upload.component.html 
I set

```
  <td>{{ file.lastModifiedDate | date }} </td>
```

where is my mistake?

Comment: Please describe your problem more detailed. What does happen? A Pipe normally must not be imported in the component but in the `@NgModule` where you want it to use under `declarations: []`.

Comment: import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({

 declarations: [  CommonModule]  }) here in app.module.ts?

Comment: @MaKobi now I have error `compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'CommonModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.`

Answer (score 0):

The `DatePipe` shouldn't need to be imported at all.
It's built in and can be used out of the box

Comment: why does not it works? `  <td>{{ file.lastModifiedDate | date }} </td> `